# how to run profile mode for Flutter embeded in Android app

Tags: android, flutter

if i build an flutter app, it is easy to run it in profile mode.

but now the case is a FlutterFragment is embeded in Android app. the host is Android app rather than flutter app.

the things works for flutter app dont work any more, including "Run--- Flutter Run app in profile mode".

so how can i run my FlutterFragment in profile mode.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the tools your using before posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: off course，i did. but i cant find any documentation on the case i met. all the documentation is about flutter app.